# Transparent finite wells

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

If the transparency coefficient for a scattering particle in a finite potential well is $T=1$ then the energies are that of a particle in a infinite potential well.

Why is this? Is this a coincidence or is there a reason behind this? Doesn't $T=1$ imply that the well is 'transparent' and so the particle isn't affected by the potential at all? I would have thought $T=0$ would give energies for an infinite potential well instead since $T=0$ implies a boundary? I understand the mathematics but I can't get the intuition.

Comment: $T$ is a function of the incoming wavelength. Do you want it to be $1$ for all incoming?

Comment: What do you mean by: "the energies are that of a particle in a infinite potential well."?

Answer (score 0):

$T=1$ indeed means that the well is transparent for the particle at this energy ($T(E)$ is a function of the particle energy, which takes value unity only for some energies). This indeed happens only when special resonant conditions are satisfied, such as the integer number of wavelengths fitting between the two edges of the well, which is why the states resemble those in the infinite potential well: more precisely, they have similar energies, but not encessarily zero at the boundary of the well, and certainly not zero outside of it.

$T=0$ means full reflection of the incident wave - it is however easy to check that it never happens for the particles with energies above the well.